# How to get all radio button value into Json and load using local storage?

Tags: jquery, json, local-storage

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $('#showme').click(function() {
    //validateNresult() ;
    exportResultJson();
  })


  $('.allrb').change(valueE);

});

function validateNresult() {

  var firstInvalidRowIndex = 0;
  $.each($("tbody tr"), function(i, e) {
    var hasInvalidInputs = $(this).find(".numFr, .numIr").filter(function() {
      return $.trim(this.value).length === 0;
    }).length > 0;

    if (hasInvalidInputs) {
      $(this).addClass("invalid");
      if (firstInvalidRowIndex <= 0) {
        firstInvalidRowIndex = i + 1;
      }
    } else {
      $(this).removeClass("invalid");
    }

  });

  if (firstInvalidRowIndex > 0) {
    $('html, body').animate({
      scrollTop: ($("#alertr1").offset().top)
    }, 1000);
  }
}



function valueE(e) {
  var newValue = e.target.value;
  var $radio = $(e.target);

  if ($radio.is('.Fr')) {
    $radio.closest('tr').find('.numFr').val(newValue);
  } else {
    $radio.closest('tr').find('.numIr').val(newValue);
  }
}


$(document).ready(function() {
  importResultJson();

});


function exportResultJson() {
  var fav, favs = [];
  $('.allrb').each(function() { // run through each of the checkboxes
    fav = {
      name: $(this).attr('name'),
      value: $(this).prop('checked')
    };
    favs.push(fav);
  });


  localStorage.setItem("favorites", JSON.stringify(favs));
  console.log(favs);
}

function importResultJson() {
  var favorites = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('favorites'));
  if (!favorites.length) {
    return
  };
  console.debug(favorites);

  for (var i = 0; i < favorites.length; i++) {
    //console.debug(favorites[i].value == 'on');
    //$('#' + favorites[i].id ).prop('checked', favorites[i].value);
    $('[name=' + favorites[i].name + ']').prop('checked', favorites[i].value);

  }

}

function page_onLoad() {
  if (Moodle_getParam("attempt_id")) {
    Moodle_Retrieve_QuizResult(Moodle_getParam("attempt_id"), function(data) {
      importResultJson();
    });
  }

}
```

```css
input[type=number] {
  width: 25px;
  text-align: center;
}

.invalid {
  outline: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="table table-hover table-responsive" id="tab">
  <tr id="alertr1" name="v">
    <td width="200px" id="text">content 1</td>
    <td width="40px">
      <label>
        <input type="radio" name="Fr1" class="allrb Fr" value="0">
      </label>
    </td>
    <td width="40px">
      <label>
        <input type="radio" name="Fr1" class="allrb Fr" value="1">
      </label>
    </td>
    <td width="40px">
      <label>
        <input type="radio" name="Fr1" class="allrb Fr" value="2">
      </label>
    </td>
    <td width="40px">
      <label>
        <input type="radio" name="Fr1" class="allrb Fr" value="3">
      </label>
    </td>
    <td width="30px">
      <label>
        <input type="radio" name="Fr1" class="allrb Fr" value="4">
      </label>
    </td>
    <td width="50px" bgcolor="Gainsboro">
      <label>
        <input type="radio" name="Ir1" class="allrb Ir" value="0">
      </label>
    </td>
    <td width="50px" bgcolor="Gainsboro">
      <label>
        <input type="radio" name="Ir1" class="allrb Ir" value="1">
      </label>
    </td>
    <td width="50px" bgcolor="Gainsboro">
      <label>
        <input type="radio" name="Ir1" class="allrb Ir" value="2">
      </label>
    </td>
    <td width="50px" bgcolor="Gainsboro">
      <label>
        <input type="radio" name="Ir1" class="allrb Ir" value="3">
      </label>
    </td>
    <td width="120px" bgcolor="Gainsboro">
      <label>
        <input type="radio" name="Ir1" class="allrb Ir" value="4">
      </label>
    </td>
    <td width="30px">
      <input type="number" name="numFr1" class="numFr" id="numFr1" disabled>
    </td>
    <td width="30px" bgcolor="Gainsboro">
      <input type="number" name="numIr1" class="numIr" id="numIr1" disabled>
    </td>
  </tr>

  <tr id="alertr2" name="v">
    <td width="200px" id="text">content 2</td>
    <td width="40px">
      <label>
        <input type="radio" name="Fr2" class="allrb Fr" value="0">
      </label>
    </td>
    <td width="40px">
      <label>
        <input type="radio" name="Fr2" class="allrb Fr" value="1">
      </label>
    </td>
    <td width="40px">
      <label>
        <input type="radio" name="Fr2" class="allrb Fr" value="2">
      </label>
    </td>
    <td width="40px">
      <label>
        <input type="radio" name="Fr2" class="allrb Fr" value="3">
      </label>
    </td>
    <td width="30px">
      <label>
        <input type="radio" name="Fr2" class="allrb Fr" value="4">
      </label>
    </td>
    <td width="50px" bgcolor="Gainsboro">
      <label>
        <input type="radio" name="Ir2" class="allrb Ir" value="0">
      </label>
    </td>
    <td width="50px" bgcolor="Gainsboro">
      <label>
        <input type="radio" name="Ir2" class="allrb Ir" value="1">
      </label>
    </td>
    <td width="50px" bgcolor="Gainsboro">
      <label>
        <input type="radio" name="Ir2" class="allrb Ir" value="2">
      </label>
    </td>
    <td width="50px" bgcolor="Gainsboro">
      <label>
        <input type="radio" name="Ir2" class="allrb Ir" value="3">
      </label>
    </td>
    <td width="120px" bgcolor="Gainsboro">
      <label>
        <input type="radio" name="Ir2" class="allrb Ir" value="4">
      </label>
    </td>
    <td width="30px">
      <input type="number" name="numFr2" class="numFr" id="numFr2" disabled>
    </td>
    <td width="30px" bgcolor="Gainsboro">
      <input type="number" name="numIr2" class="numIr" id="numIr2" disabled>
    </td>
  </tr>

  <tr id="alertr3" name="v">
    <td width="200px" id="text">content 3</td>
    <td width="40px">
      <label>
        <input type="radio" name="Fr3" class="allrb Fr" value="0">
      </label>
    </td>
    <td width="40px">
      <label>
        <input type="radio" name="Fr3" class="allrb Fr" value="1">
      </label>
    </td>
    <td width="40px">
      <label>
        <input type="radio" name="Fr3" class="allrb Fr" value="2">
      </label>
    </td>
    <td width="40px">
      <label>
        <input type="radio" name="Fr3" class="allrb Fr" value="3">
      </label>
    </td>
    <td width="30px">
      <label>
        <input type="radio" name="Fr3" class="allrb Fr" value="4">
      </label>
    </td>
    <td width="50px" bgcolor="Gainsboro">
      <label>
        <input type="radio" name="Ir3" class="allrb" value="0">
      </label>
    </td>
    <td width="50px" bgcolor="Gainsboro">
      <label>
        <input type="radio" name="Ir3" class="allrb" value="1">
      </label>
    </td>
    <td width="50px" bgcolor="Gainsboro">
      <label>
        <input type="radio" name="Ir3" class="allrb" value="2">
      </label>
    </td>
    <td width="50px" bgcolor="Gainsboro">
      <label>
        <input type="radio" name="Ir3" class="allrb" value="3">
      </label>
    </td>
    <td width="120px" bgcolor="Gainsboro">
      <label>
        <input type="radio" name="Ir3" class="allrb" value="4">
      </label>
    </td>
    <td width="30px">
      <input type="number" name="numFr3" class="numFr" id="numFr3" disabled>
    </td>
    <td width="30px" bgcolor="Gainsboro">
      <input type="number" name="numIr3" class="numIr" id="numIr3" disabled>
    </td>
  </tr>

  <tr id="alertr4" name="v">
    <td width="200px" id="text">content 4</td>
    <td width="40px">
      <label>
        <input type="radio" name="Fr4" class="allrb Fr" value="0">
      </label>
    </td>
    <td width="40px">
      <label>
        <input type="radio" name="Fr4" class="allrb Fr" value="1">
      </label>
    </td>
    <td width="40px">
      <label>
        <input type="radio" name="Fr4" class="allrb Fr" value="2">
      </label>
    </td>
    <td width="40px">
      <label>
        <input type="radio" name="Fr4" class="allrb Fr" value="3">
      </label>
    </td>
    <td width="30px">
      <label>
        <input type="radio" name="Fr4" class="allrb Fr" value="4">
      </label>
    </td>
    <td width="50px" bgcolor="Gainsboro">
      <label>
        <input type="radio" name="Ir4" class="allrb" value="0">
      </label>
    </td>
    <td width="50px" bgcolor="Gainsboro">
      <label>
        <input type="radio" name="Ir4" class="allrb" value="1">
      </label>
    </td>
    <td width="50px" bgcolor="Gainsboro">
      <label>
        <input type="radio" name="Ir4" class="allrb" value="2">
      </label>
    </td>
    <td width="50px" bgcolor="Gainsboro">
      <label>
        <input type="radio" name="Ir4" class="allrb" value="3">
      </label>
    </td>
    <td width="120px" bgcolor="Gainsboro">
      <label>
        <input type="radio" name="Ir4" class="allrb" value="4">
      </label>
    </td>
    <td width="30px">
      <input type="number" name="numFr4" class="numFr" id="numFr4" disabled>
    </td>
    <td width="30px" bgcolor="Gainsboro">
      <input type="number" name="numIr4" class="numIr" id="numIr4" disabled>
    </td>
  </tr>

  <tr id="alertr5" name="v">
    <td width="200px" id="text">content 5</td>
    <td width="40px">
      <label>
        <input type="radio" name="Fr5" class="allrb Fr" value="0">
      </label>
    </td>
    <td width="40px">
      <label>
        <input type="radio" name="Fr5" class="allrb Fr" value="1">
      </label>
    </td>
    <td width="40px">
      <label>
        <input type="radio" name="Fr5" class="allrb Fr" value="2">
      </label>
    </td>
    <td width="40px">
      <label>
        <input type="radio" name="Fr5" class="allrb Fr" value="3">
      </label>
    </td>
    <td width="30px">
      <label>
        <input type="radio" name="Fr5" class="allrb Fr" value="4">
      </label>
    </td>
    <td width="50px" bgcolor="Gainsboro">
      <label>
        <input type="radio" name="Ir5" class="allrb" value="0">
      </label>
    </td>
    <td width="50px" bgcolor="Gainsboro">
      <label>
        <input type="radio" name="Ir5" class="allrb" value="1">
      </label>
    </td>
    <td width="50px" bgcolor="Gainsboro">
      <label>
        <input type="radio" name="Ir5" class="allrb" value="2">
      </label>
    </td>
    <td width="50px" bgcolor="Gainsboro">
      <label>
        <input type="radio" name="Ir5" class="allrb" value="3">
      </label>
    </td>
    <td width="120px" bgcolor="Gainsboro">
      <label>
        <input type="radio" name="Ir5" class="allrb" value="4">
      </label>
    </td>
    <td width="30px">
      <input type="number" name="numFr5" class="numFr" id="numFr5" disabled>
    </td>
    <td width="30px" bgcolor="Gainsboro">
      <input type="number" name="numIr5" class="numIr" id="numIr5" disabled>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr id="alertr6" name="v">
    <td width="200px" id="text">content 6</td>
    <td width="40px">
      <label>
        <input type="radio" name="Fr6" class="allrb Fr" value="0">
      </label>
    </td>
    <td width="40px">
      <label>
        <input type="radio" name="Fr6" class="allrb Fr" value="1">
      </label>
    </td>
    <td width="40px">
      <label>
        <input type="radio" name="Fr6" class="allrb Fr" value="2">
      </label>
    </td>
    <td width="40px">
      <label>
        <input type="radio" name="Fr6" class="allrb Fr" value="3">
      </label>
    </td>
    <td width="30px">
      <label>
        <input type="radio" name="Fr6" class="allrb Fr" value="4">
      </label>
    </td>
    <td width="50px" bgcolor="Gainsboro">
      <label>
        <input type="radio" name="Ir6" class="allrb" value="0">
      </label>
    </td>
    <td width="50px" bgcolor="Gainsboro">
      <label>
        <input type="radio" name="Ir6" class="allrb" value="1">
      </label>
    </td>
    <td width="50px" bgcolor="Gainsboro">
      <label>
        <input type="radio" name="Ir6" class="allrb" value="2">
      </label>
    </td>
    <td width="50px" bgcolor="Gainsboro">
      <label>
        <input type="radio" name="Ir6" class="allrb" value="3">
      </label>
    </td>
    <td width="120px" bgcolor="Gainsboro">
      <label>
        <input type="radio" name="Ir6" class="allrb" value="4">
      </label>
    </td>
    <td width="30px">
      <input type="number" name="numFr6" class="numFr" id="numFr6" disabled>
    </td>
    <td width="30px" bgcolor="Gainsboro">
      <input type="number" name="numIr6" class="numIr" id="numIr6" disabled>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr id="alertr7" name="v">
    <td width="200px" id="text">content 7</td>
    <td width="40px">
      <label>
        <input type="radio" name="Fr7" class="allrb Fr" value="0">
      </label>
    </td>
    <td width="40px">
      <label>
        <input type="radio" name="Fr7" class="allrb Fr" value="1">
      </label>
    </td>
    <td width="40px">
      <label>
        <input type="radio" name="Fr7" class="allrb Fr" value="2">
      </label>
    </td>
    <td width="40px">
      <label>
        <input type="radio" name="Fr7" class="allrb Fr" value="3">
      </label>
    </td>
    <td width="30px">
      <label>
        <input type="radio" name="Fr7" class="allrb Fr" value="4">
      </label>
    </td>
    <td width="50px" bgcolor="Gainsboro">
      <label>
        <input type="radio" name="Ir7" class="allrb" value="0">
      </label>
    </td>
    <td width="50px" bgcolor="Gainsboro">
      <label>
        <input type="radio" name="Ir7" class="allrb" value="1">
      </label>
    </td>
    <td width="50px" bgcolor="Gainsboro">
      <label>
        <input type="radio" name="Ir7" class="allrb" value="2">
      </label>
    </td>
    <td width="50px" bgcolor="Gainsboro">
      <label>
        <input type="radio" name="Ir7" class="allrb" value="3">
      </label>
    </td>
    <td width="120px" bgcolor="Gainsboro">
      <label>
        <input type="radio" name="Ir7" class="allrb" value="4">
      </label>
    </td>
    <td width="30px">
      <input type="number" name="numFr7" class="numFr" id="numFr7" disabled>
    </td>
    <td width="30px" bgcolor="Gainsboro">
      <input type="number" name="numIr7" class="numIr" id="numIr7" disabled>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr id="alertr8" name="v">
    <td width="200px" id="text">content 8</td>
    <td width="40px">
      <label>
        <input type="radio" name="Fr8" class="allrb Fr" value="0">
      </label>
    </td>
    <td width="40px">
      <label>
        <input type="radio" name="Fr8" class="allrb Fr" value="1">
      </label>
    </td>
    <td width="40px">
      <label>
        <input type="radio" name="Fr8" class="allrb Fr" value="2">
      </label>
    </td>
    <td width="40px">
      <label>
        <input type="radio" name="Fr8" class="allrb Fr" value="3">
      </label>
    </td>
    <td width="30px">
      <label>
        <input type="radio" name="Fr8" class="allrb Fr" value="4">
      </label>
    </td>
    <td width="50px" bgcolor="Gainsboro">
      <label>
        <input type="radio" name="Ir8" class="allrb" value="0">
      </label>
    </td>
    <td width="50px" bgcolor="Gainsboro">
      <label>
        <input type="radio" name="Ir8" class="allrb" value="1">
      </label>
    </td>
    <td width="50px" bgcolor="Gainsboro">
      <label>
        <input type="radio" name="Ir8" class="allrb" value="2">
      </label>
    </td>
    <td width="50px" bgcolor="Gainsboro">
      <label>
        <input type="radio" name="Ir8" class="allrb" value="3">
      </label>
    </td>
    <td width="120px" bgcolor="Gainsboro">
      <label>
        <input type="radio" name="Ir8" class="allrb" value="4">
      </label>
    </td>
    <td width="30px">
      <input type="number" name="numFr8" class="numFr" id="numFr8" disabled>
    </td>
    <td width="30px" bgcolor="Gainsboro">
      <input type="number" name="numIr8" class="numIr" id="numIr8" disabled>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr id="alertr9" name="v">
    <td width="200px" id="text">content 9</td>
    <td width="40px">
      <label>
        <input type="radio" name="Fr9" class="allrb Fr" value="0">
      </label>
    </td>
    <td width="40px">
      <label>
        <input type="radio" name="Fr9" class="allrb Fr" value="1">
      </label>
    </td>
    <td width="40px">
      <label>
        <input type="radio" name="Fr9" class="allrb Fr" value="2">
      </label>
    </td>
    <td width="40px">
      <label>
        <input type="radio" name="Fr9" class="allrb Fr" value="3">
      </label>
    </td>
    <td width="30px">
      <label>
        <input type="radio" name="Fr9" class="allrb Fr" value="4">
      </label>
    </td>
    <td width="50px" bgcolor="Gainsboro">
      <label>
        <input type="radio" name="Ir9" class="allrb" value="0">
      </label>
    </td>
    <td width="50px" bgcolor="Gainsboro">
      <label>
        <input type="radio" name="Ir9" class="allrb" value="1">
      </label>
    </td>
    <td width="50px" bgcolor="Gainsboro">
      <label>
        <input type="radio" name="Ir9" class="allrb" value="2">
      </label>
    </td>
    <td width="50px" bgcolor="Gainsboro">
      <label>
        <input type="radio" name="Ir9" class="allrb" value="3">
      </label>
    </td>
    <td width="120px" bgcolor="Gainsboro">
      <label>
        <input type="radio" name="Ir9" class="allrb" value="4">
      </label>
    </td>
    <td width="30px">
      <input type="number" name="numFr9" class="numFr" id="numFr9" disabled>
    </td>
    <td width="30px" bgcolor="Gainsboro">
      <input type="number" name="numIr9" class="numIr" id="numIr9" disabled>
    </td>
  </tr>

</table>


<button class="btn btn-primary" id="showme" type="button">View Result</button>
<p style="float:right;position:absolute;margin-left:700px;margin-top:10px;" id="alertmessage"></p>
```

I had already success to store all the radio button value into Json using localstorage setItem, but I don't know why, it call only half of my store value. You may understand when you see my fiddle.
First you had to select some value for radio box then click the button and refresh again the page. 
[image: Select and store to Json.]

[image: After refresh the red border are not being call but the another part is being call]

After refresh. May I know where the probelm is? Thanks.

[Here is the fiddle.](https://fiddle.jshell.net/zsg5fuar/)

Comment: Maybe jsfiddle does not allow to write into local storage. Got this error `Uncaught DOMException: Failed to read the 'localStorage' property from 'Window': Access is denied for this document.` Try it on your own server.

Comment: for me local storage is working on chrome is not a problem with jsfiddle

Comment: @Phil Yeah,I'm sure can work on fiddle. But is nevermind you can't get it. Thanks anyway.

Comment: Post your code here, not just at a remote site. You can use [Stack Snippets](https://stackoverflow.blog/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/) to make it executable.

Comment: @Barmar Stack Snippets can support for the localstorage? =O

Comment: @Barmar The code was update already, please check it. But I can't access local storage in this snippet.

Comment: @Beginner No, it doesn't allow it. But you should still post your code here even if it doesn't run.

Comment: I ran your jsfiddle and it put all the radio buttons into local storage.

Comment: @Barmar Yes, because I don't know how to store only the check value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you're just putting the name of the radio button into the local storage elements. But all the buttons in a group have the same name, and you don't distinguish which button in the group you're storing.

You should just store the value of the buttons that are checked. Then when restoring, you check that specific button in each group.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $('#showme').click(function() {
    //validateNresult() ;
    exportResultJson();
  })


  $('.allrb').change(valueE);

});

$(document).ready(function() {
  importResultJson();

});

function exportResultJson() {
  var fav, favs = [];
  $('.allrb:checked').each(function() { // run through each of the checkboxes
    fav = {
      name: $(this).attr('name'),
      value: $(this).val()
    };
    favs.push(fav);
  });

  localStorage.setItem("favorites", JSON.stringify(favs));
  console.log(favs);
}

function importResultJson() {
  var favorites = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('favorites'));
  if (!favorites.length) {
    return
  };
  console.debug(favorites);

  for (var i = 0; i < favorites.length; i++) {
    //console.debug(favorites[i].value == 'on');
    //$('#' + favorites[i].id ).prop('checked', favorites[i].value);
    $('[name=' + favorites[i].name + '][value=' + favorites[i].value + ']').prop('checked', true);

  }

}

function valueE(e) {
  var newValue = e.target.value;
  var $radio = $(e.target);

  if ($radio.is('.Fr')) {
    $radio.closest('tr').find('.numFr').val(newValue);
  } else {
    $radio.closest('tr').find('.numIr').val(newValue);
  }
}
```

```css
input[type=number] {
  width: 25px;
  text-align: center;
}

.invalid {
  outline: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="table table-hover table-responsive" id="tab">
  <tr id="alertr1" name="v">
    <td width="200px" id="text">content 1</td>
    <td width="40px">
      <label>
        <input type="radio" name="Fr1" class="allrb Fr" value="0">
      </label>
    </td>
    <td width="40px">
      <label>
        <input type="radio" name="Fr1" class="allrb Fr" value="1">
      </label>
    </td>
    <td width="40px">
      <label>
        <input type="radio" name="Fr1" class="allrb Fr" value="2">
      </label>
    </td>
    <td width="40px">
      <label>
        <input type="radio" name="Fr1" class="allrb Fr" value="3">
      </label>
    </td>
    <td width="30px">
      <label>
        <input type="radio" name="Fr1" class="allrb Fr" value="4">
      </label>
    </td>
    <td width="50px" bgcolor="Gainsboro">
      <label>
        <input type="radio" name="Ir1" class="allrb Ir" value="0">
      </label>
    </td>
    <td width="50px" bgcolor="Gainsboro">
      <label>
        <input type="radio" name="Ir1" class="allrb Ir" value="1">
      </label>
    </td>
    <td width="50px" bgcolor="Gainsboro">
      <label>
        <input type="radio" name="Ir1" class="allrb Ir" value="2">
      </label>
    </td>
    <td width="50px" bgcolor="Gainsboro">
      <label>
        <input type="radio" name="Ir1" class="allrb Ir" value="3">
      </label>
    </td>
    <td width="120px" bgcolor="Gainsboro">
      <label>
        <input type="radio" name="Ir1" class="allrb Ir" value="4">
      </label>
    </td>
    <td width="30px">
      <input type="number" name="numFr1" class="numFr" id="numFr1" disabled>
    </td>
    <td width="30px" bgcolor="Gainsboro">
      <input type="number" name="numIr1" class="numIr" id="numIr1" disabled>
    </td>
  </tr>

  <tr id="alertr2" name="v">
    <td width="200px" id="text">content 2</td>
    <td width="40px">
      <label>
        <input type="radio" name="Fr2" class="allrb Fr" value="0">
      </label>
    </td>
    <td width="40px">
      <label>
        <input type="radio" name="Fr2" class="allrb Fr" value="1">
      </label>
    </td>
    <td width="40px">
      <label>
        <input type="radio" name="Fr2" class="allrb Fr" value="2">
      </label>
    </td>
    <td width="40px">
      <label>
        <input type="radio" name="Fr2" class="allrb Fr" value="3">
      </label>
    </td>
    <td width="30px">
      <label>
        <input type="radio" name="Fr2" class="allrb Fr" value="4">
      </label>
    </td>
    <td width="50px" bgcolor="Gainsboro">
      <label>
        <input type="radio" name="Ir2" class="allrb Ir" value="0">
      </label>
    </td>
    <td width="50px" bgcolor="Gainsboro">
      <label>
        <input type="radio" name="Ir2" class="allrb Ir" value="1">
      </label>
    </td>
    <td width="50px" bgcolor="Gainsboro">
      <label>
        <input type="radio" name="Ir2" class="allrb Ir" value="2">
      </label>
    </td>
    <td width="50px" bgcolor="Gainsboro">
      <label>
        <input type="radio" name="Ir2" class="allrb Ir" value="3">
      </label>
    </td>
    <td width="120px" bgcolor="Gainsboro">
      <label>
        <input type="radio" name="Ir2" class="allrb Ir" value="4">
      </label>
    </td>
    <td width="30px">
      <input type="number" name="numFr2" class="numFr" id="numFr2" disabled>
    </td>
    <td width="30px" bgcolor="Gainsboro">
      <input type="number" name="numIr2" class="numIr" id="numIr2" disabled>
    </td>
  </tr>

  <tr id="alertr3" name="v">
    <td width="200px" id="text">content 3</td>
    <td width="40px">
      <label>
        <input type="radio" name="Fr3" class="allrb Fr" value="0">
      </label>
    </td>
    <td width="40px">
      <label>
        <input type="radio" name="Fr3" class="allrb Fr" value="1">
      </label>
    </td>
    <td width="40px">
      <label>
        <input type="radio" name="Fr3" class="allrb Fr" value="2">
      </label>
    </td>
    <td width="40px">
      <label>
        <input type="radio" name="Fr3" class="allrb Fr" value="3">
      </label>
    </td>
    <td width="30px">
      <label>
        <input type="radio" name="Fr3" class="allrb Fr" value="4">
      </label>
    </td>
    <td width="50px" bgcolor="Gainsboro">
      <label>
        <input type="radio" name="Ir3" class="allrb" value="0">
      </label>
    </td>
    <td width="50px" bgcolor="Gainsboro">
      <label>
        <input type="radio" name="Ir3" class="allrb" value="1">
      </label>
    </td>
    <td width="50px" bgcolor="Gainsboro">
      <label>
        <input type="radio" name="Ir3" class="allrb" value="2">
      </label>
    </td>
    <td width="50px" bgcolor="Gainsboro">
      <label>
        <input type="radio" name="Ir3" class="allrb" value="3">
      </label>
    </td>
    <td width="120px" bgcolor="Gainsboro">
      <label>
        <input type="radio" name="Ir3" class="allrb" value="4">
      </label>
    </td>
    <td width="30px">
      <input type="number" name="numFr3" class="numFr" id="numFr3" disabled>
    </td>
    <td width="30px" bgcolor="Gainsboro">
      <input type="number" name="numIr3" class="numIr" id="numIr3" disabled>
    </td>
  </tr>

  <tr id="alertr4" name="v">
    <td width="200px" id="text">content 4</td>
    <td width="40px">
      <label>
        <input type="radio" name="Fr4" class="allrb Fr" value="0">
      </label>
    </td>
    <td width="40px">
      <label>
        <input type="radio" name="Fr4" class="allrb Fr" value="1">
      </label>
    </td>
    <td width="40px">
      <label>
        <input type="radio" name="Fr4" class="allrb Fr" value="2">
      </label>
    </td>
    <td width="40px">
      <label>
        <input type="radio" name="Fr4" class="allrb Fr" value="3">
      </label>
    </td>
    <td width="30px">
      <label>
        <input type="radio" name="Fr4" class="allrb Fr" value="4">
      </label>
    </td>
    <td width="50px" bgcolor="Gainsboro">
      <label>
        <input type="radio" name="Ir4" class="allrb" value="0">
      </label>
    </td>
    <td width="50px" bgcolor="Gainsboro">
      <label>
        <input type="radio" name="Ir4" class="allrb" value="1">
      </label>
    </td>
    <td width="50px" bgcolor="Gainsboro">
      <label>
        <input type="radio" name="Ir4" class="allrb" value="2">
      </label>
    </td>
    <td width="50px" bgcolor="Gainsboro">
      <label>
        <input type="radio" name="Ir4" class="allrb" value="3">
      </label>
    </td>
    <td width="120px" bgcolor="Gainsboro">
      <label>
        <input type="radio" name="Ir4" class="allrb" value="4">
      </label>
    </td>
    <td width="30px">
      <input type="number" name="numFr4" class="numFr" id="numFr4" disabled>
    </td>
    <td width="30px" bgcolor="Gainsboro">
      <input type="number" name="numIr4" class="numIr" id="numIr4" disabled>
    </td>
  </tr>

  <tr id="alertr5" name="v">
    <td width="200px" id="text">content 5</td>
    <td width="40px">
      <label>
        <input type="radio" name="Fr5" class="allrb Fr" value="0">
      </label>
    </td>
    <td width="40px">
      <label>
        <input type="radio" name="Fr5" class="allrb Fr" value="1">
      </label>
    </td>
    <td width="40px">
      <label>
        <input type="radio" name="Fr5" class="allrb Fr" value="2">
      </label>
    </td>
    <td width="40px">
      <label>
        <input type="radio" name="Fr5" class="allrb Fr" value="3">
      </label>
    </td>
    <td width="30px">
      <label>
        <input type="radio" name="Fr5" class="allrb Fr" value="4">
      </label>
    </td>
    <td width="50px" bgcolor="Gainsboro">
      <label>
        <input type="radio" name="Ir5" class="allrb" value="0">
      </label>
    </td>
    <td width="50px" bgcolor="Gainsboro">
      <label>
        <input type="radio" name="Ir5" class="allrb" value="1">
      </label>
    </td>
    <td width="50px" bgcolor="Gainsboro">
      <label>
        <input type="radio" name="Ir5" class="allrb" value="2">
      </label>
    </td>
    <td width="50px" bgcolor="Gainsboro">
      <label>
        <input type="radio" name="Ir5" class="allrb" value="3">
      </label>
    </td>
    <td width="120px" bgcolor="Gainsboro">
      <label>
        <input type="radio" name="Ir5" class="allrb" value="4">
      </label>
    </td>
    <td width="30px">
      <input type="number" name="numFr5" class="numFr" id="numFr5" disabled>
    </td>
    <td width="30px" bgcolor="Gainsboro">
      <input type="number" name="numIr5" class="numIr" id="numIr5" disabled>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr id="alertr6" name="v">
    <td width="200px" id="text">content 6</td>
    <td width="40px">
      <label>
        <input type="radio" name="Fr6" class="allrb Fr" value="0">
      </label>
    </td>
    <td width="40px">
      <label>
        <input type="radio" name="Fr6" class="allrb Fr" value="1">
      </label>
    </td>
    <td width="40px">
      <label>
        <input type="radio" name="Fr6" class="allrb Fr" value="2">
      </label>
    </td>
    <td width="40px">
      <label>
        <input type="radio" name="Fr6" class="allrb Fr" value="3">
      </label>
    </td>
    <td width="30px">
      <label>
        <input type="radio" name="Fr6" class="allrb Fr" value="4">
      </label>
    </td>
    <td width="50px" bgcolor="Gainsboro">
      <label>
        <input type="radio" name="Ir6" class="allrb" value="0">
      </label>
    </td>
    <td width="50px" bgcolor="Gainsboro">
      <label>
        <input type="radio" name="Ir6" class="allrb" value="1">
      </label>
    </td>
    <td width="50px" bgcolor="Gainsboro">
      <label>
        <input type="radio" name="Ir6" class="allrb" value="2">
      </label>
    </td>
    <td width="50px" bgcolor="Gainsboro">
      <label>
        <input type="radio" name="Ir6" class="allrb" value="3">
      </label>
    </td>
    <td width="120px" bgcolor="Gainsboro">
      <label>
        <input type="radio" name="Ir6" class="allrb" value="4">
      </label>
    </td>
    <td width="30px">
      <input type="number" name="numFr6" class="numFr" id="numFr6" disabled>
    </td>
    <td width="30px" bgcolor="Gainsboro">
      <input type="number" name="numIr6" class="numIr" id="numIr6" disabled>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr id="alertr7" name="v">
    <td width="200px" id="text">content 7</td>
    <td width="40px">
      <label>
        <input type="radio" name="Fr7" class="allrb Fr" value="0">
      </label>
    </td>
    <td width="40px">
      <label>
        <input type="radio" name="Fr7" class="allrb Fr" value="1">
      </label>
    </td>
    <td width="40px">
      <label>
        <input type="radio" name="Fr7" class="allrb Fr" value="2">
      </label>
    </td>
    <td width="40px">
      <label>
        <input type="radio" name="Fr7" class="allrb Fr" value="3">
      </label>
    </td>
    <td width="30px">
      <label>
        <input type="radio" name="Fr7" class="allrb Fr" value="4">
      </label>
    </td>
    <td width="50px" bgcolor="Gainsboro">
      <label>
        <input type="radio" name="Ir7" class="allrb" value="0">
      </label>
    </td>
    <td width="50px" bgcolor="Gainsboro">
      <label>
        <input type="radio" name="Ir7" class="allrb" value="1">
      </label>
    </td>
    <td width="50px" bgcolor="Gainsboro">
      <label>
        <input type="radio" name="Ir7" class="allrb" value="2">
      </label>
    </td>
    <td width="50px" bgcolor="Gainsboro">
      <label>
        <input type="radio" name="Ir7" class="allrb" value="3">
      </label>
    </td>
    <td width="120px" bgcolor="Gainsboro">
      <label>
        <input type="radio" name="Ir7" class="allrb" value="4">
      </label>
    </td>
    <td width="30px">
      <input type="number" name="numFr7" class="numFr" id="numFr7" disabled>
    </td>
    <td width="30px" bgcolor="Gainsboro">
      <input type="number" name="numIr7" class="numIr" id="numIr7" disabled>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr id="alertr8" name="v">
    <td width="200px" id="text">content 8</td>
    <td width="40px">
      <label>
        <input type="radio" name="Fr8" class="allrb Fr" value="0">
      </label>
    </td>
    <td width="40px">
      <label>
        <input type="radio" name="Fr8" class="allrb Fr" value="1">
      </label>
    </td>
    <td width="40px">
      <label>
        <input type="radio" name="Fr8" class="allrb Fr" value="2">
      </label>
    </td>
    <td width="40px">
      <label>
        <input type="radio" name="Fr8" class="allrb Fr" value="3">
      </label>
    </td>
    <td width="30px">
      <label>
        <input type="radio" name="Fr8" class="allrb Fr" value="4">
      </label>
    </td>
    <td width="50px" bgcolor="Gainsboro">
      <label>
        <input type="radio" name="Ir8" class="allrb" value="0">
      </label>
    </td>
    <td width="50px" bgcolor="Gainsboro">
      <label>
        <input type="radio" name="Ir8" class="allrb" value="1">
      </label>
    </td>
    <td width="50px" bgcolor="Gainsboro">
      <label>
        <input type="radio" name="Ir8" class="allrb" value="2">
      </label>
    </td>
    <td width="50px" bgcolor="Gainsboro">
      <label>
        <input type="radio" name="Ir8" class="allrb" value="3">
      </label>
    </td>
    <td width="120px" bgcolor="Gainsboro">
      <label>
        <input type="radio" name="Ir8" class="allrb" value="4">
      </label>
    </td>
    <td width="30px">
      <input type="number" name="numFr8" class="numFr" id="numFr8" disabled>
    </td>
    <td width="30px" bgcolor="Gainsboro">
      <input type="number" name="numIr8" class="numIr" id="numIr8" disabled>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr id="alertr9" name="v">
    <td width="200px" id="text">content 9</td>
    <td width="40px">
      <label>
        <input type="radio" name="Fr9" class="allrb Fr" value="0">
      </label>
    </td>
    <td width="40px">
      <label>
        <input type="radio" name="Fr9" class="allrb Fr" value="1">
      </label>
    </td>
    <td width="40px">
      <label>
        <input type="radio" name="Fr9" class="allrb Fr" value="2">
      </label>
    </td>
    <td width="40px">
      <label>
        <input type="radio" name="Fr9" class="allrb Fr" value="3">
      </label>
    </td>
    <td width="30px">
      <label>
        <input type="radio" name="Fr9" class="allrb Fr" value="4">
      </label>
    </td>
    <td width="50px" bgcolor="Gainsboro">
      <label>
        <input type="radio" name="Ir9" class="allrb" value="0">
      </label>
    </td>
    <td width="50px" bgcolor="Gainsboro">
      <label>
        <input type="radio" name="Ir9" class="allrb" value="1">
      </label>
    </td>
    <td width="50px" bgcolor="Gainsboro">
      <label>
        <input type="radio" name="Ir9" class="allrb" value="2">
      </label>
    </td>
    <td width="50px" bgcolor="Gainsboro">
      <label>
        <input type="radio" name="Ir9" class="allrb" value="3">
      </label>
    </td>
    <td width="120px" bgcolor="Gainsboro">
      <label>
        <input type="radio" name="Ir9" class="allrb" value="4">
      </label>
    </td>
    <td width="30px">
      <input type="number" name="numFr9" class="numFr" id="numFr9" disabled>
    </td>
    <td width="30px" bgcolor="Gainsboro">
      <input type="number" name="numIr9" class="numIr" id="numIr9" disabled>
    </td>
  </tr>

</table>


<button class="btn btn-primary" id="showme" type="button">View Result</button>
<p style="float:right;position:absolute;margin-left:700px;margin-top:10px;" id="alertmessage"></p>
```

[jsfiddle demo](https://fiddle.jshell.net/barmar/zsg5fuar/1/show/)

Comment: Thank you for solving my problem, because I though it can also work if I do it the way. Btw, do you know how can I also show the value of these 2 selected radio box directly when I refresh it?

Comment: Not sure what you're asking. `console.log(favorites[i].value)`?

Comment: Not, I means the right hand side of the two  `input[type=number]` value.

Comment: In `importResultJson()`, add code similar to `valueE()` that puts the value into the text box.

Comment: Sorry, but how do I find the `target value` in this case?

Comment: It's `favorites[i].value`.

Comment: The `e` is refer to target value, and the previous one I was call in this way `$('.allrb').change(valueE);` so it will know what is the target value.

Comment: Okay, let me try it =)

Comment: And to find out if it's `Fr1` or `Ir1`, use `$('[name=' + favorites[i].name + ']).is(".Fr1")`

Comment: `var newValue = favorites[i].value;
        var $radio = favorites[i].name;

        if (('$('[name=' + favorites[i].name + ']).is(".Fr")) 
        {
            $radio.closest('tr').find('.numFr').val(newValue);
        } 
        else 
        {
            $radio.closest('tr').find('.numIr').val(newValue);
        }` is there any wrong??

Comment: It should be `$radio = $('[name=' + favorites[i].name + ']);`

Comment: Ermm, I think there some problem in this line right?
`if (('$('[name=' + favorites[i].name + ']).is(".Fr"))`

Comment: You have some misplaced quotes and parentheses there.

Comment: You can just use `if ($radio.is(".Fr"))` once you set the variable.

Comment: Ahh, finally it work! I'm very appreciate for your patient.